# Scala Curried Type Mismatch

Tags: scala, currying

So i got the following function after some trial and error and research in our Textbook i could come up with a solution.

```
def prodC1(f : Int => Int) : (Int, Int) => Int = {
  def prodA1(a : Int, b : Int) : Int =
    if(a > b) 1 else f(a) * prodA1(a+1, b)
  prodA1 // Why do i need this line here 
}
```

If I don't put that there i get a Type mismatch, could someone elaborate/explain the requirement for this Line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So there are a lot of things which you need to know to actually understand the answer to this.

In Scala any `def` is a `method` which is nothing more than one of the members of some `object`. `methods` are not first class members in Scala which also means that `methods` can not exist on their own.

In Scala, the `value` of anything needs to be an `expression`. Meaning the RHS for a `def` needs to be an expression like `def abc = some-expression`. Examples of expression are `1`, `1 + 1`, `"xyz"`, `anotherMethodCallWhichWillReturnAnExpression()` etc.

And something like `def abc = xxxxxx` is not an `expression` in Scala language definition. And hence you can not do,

```
def prodC1(f : Int => Int) : (Int, Int) => Int = {
  def prodA1(a : Int, b : Int) : Int =
    if(a > b) 1 else f(a) * prodA1(a+1, b)
}
```

Now, when you are adding that extra line with `prodA1`, you are telling Scala to return this `prodA1` which you just define. But remember `prodA1` is just a `method` and hence can not exist on its own and hence can not actually be returned.

But `functions` are first class members in Scala (represented as instances of one of the various `FunctionX` classes) and hence can be returned.

In this case Scala will intelligently lift this `method` to become a `function` of type `(Int, Int) => Int`. This is called eta-expansion.

To understand things more in detail. You can open the Scala console and try the following.

```
scala> val s = "abc"
// s: String = abc

scala> val i = 10
// i: Int = 10


scala> def prodA1(a : Int, b : Int) : Int = if (a > b) 1 else a * prodA1(a+1, b)
// prodA1: (a: Int, b: Int)Int
```

Notice the difference between the output of Scala console for actual `values` and `def`. Now, if I try to use `prodA1` as `value` of a `val`, I will get following error.

```
scala> val x = prodA1
// <console>:12: error: missing argument list for method prodA1
// Unapplied methods are only converted to functions when a function type is expected.
// You can make this conversion explicit by writing `prodA1 _` or `prodA1(_,_)` instead of `prodA1`.
//        val x = prodA1
```

Scala is telling you that you can explicitly convert `method` to `function` by using a `_`. Lets try that.

```
scala> val x = prodA1 _
// x: (Int, Int) => Int = $$Lambda$1077/293669143@13278a41
```

Now `x` is a `function` of type `(Int, Int) => Int`.

Also, that first line `Unapplied methods are only converted to functions when a function type is expected.` is telling you about what actually happened in your case.

Since `prodC1` was expected to return a `function` of type `(Int, Int) => Int` and you provided `prodA1`, Scala used `eta-expansion` to automatically convert your `method` to `function`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation replacing "prodA1" with "return prodA1(,)" makes a lot more sense to me syntacticaly.

Comment: That is actually a big shift in thinking. Something like `return 1` `def abc = { return 1 }` is more like a `statement` where as `1` in `def abc = 1` is `expression`. The more you move towards functional programming, you will start finding expressions more logical than statements.

Comment: Even though i like your encouragement, I am not a very big fan of functional programming, but time will tell. :->

Answer (score 0):

Your function needs to return an instance of (Int, Int) => Int.

```
  def prodA1(a : Int, b : Int) : Int =
    if(a > b) 1 else f(a) * prodA1(a+1, b)
```

Creates a function of type `(Int, Int) => Int` with name prodA1 but the return type of **defining** an inner function does not create an instance of anything so the return type of the function is `Unit`.

Therefore you need to return the `prodA1` which has the correct type..

Answer (score 0):

Let's have a look at your return type.

```
def prodC1(f : Int => Int) : (Int, Int) => Int = {
  def prodA1(a : Int, b : Int) : Int =
    if(a > b) 1 else f(a) * prodA1(a+1, b)
  prodA1 // Why do i need this line here 
}
```

your return type is

```
 (Int, Int) => Int
```

that is scala sugar for a `Function2[Int, Int, Int]`

where the first param is the type to the first param, the second param is the type for the second param and the last is the type for the return  param

The return instance needs to be a function

prodA1 conforms to this type, meaning it is allowed to be returned.